# SESSION variable not getting passed over

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am trying to check if my `resultId` exists so I can redirect to my login page if it doesn't. From what I understand about SESSION variables, this information should be passed through to my page, but it doesn't. Right now after login, the page should redirect to the homepage, but it just goes right back to the login screen because it cannot find a value in the session for `resultId`.

My login page:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    // Define variables and set to empty values
    $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $loginErr = "";
    $loginName = $loginPass = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $valid = True;

        if (empty($_POST['loginName'])) {
            $usernameErr = "Please enter your username";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $loginName = test_input($_POST['loginName']);
            $_SESSION['loginName'] = $loginName;
        }

        if (empty($_POST['loginPass'])) {
            $passwordErr = "Please enter your password";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $loginPass = test_input($_POST['loginPass']);
            $_SESSION['loginPass'] = $loginPass;
        }

        // If valid connect to database
        if ($valid) {
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $servername = "";

            try {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=capstonedb", $username, $password);
                // Set the PDO error mode to exception
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();}

            // Select username and password from database 
            // and compare with user input.
            $sql_login = "SELECT id FROM login
                        WHERE username = '$_SESSION[loginName]'
                        AND password = '$_SESSION[loginPass]'";
            $result = $pdo->query($sql_login);
            $resultId = $result->fetch();
            $_SESSION['resultId'] = $result->fetch();           

            if ($resultId['id'] != null) {
                // Login successful 
                // Redirect to home.php
                header('location: home.php');
            } else {
                $loginErr = "Incorrect login/password";
            }   

            // Close the connection
            session_destroy();
            $pdo = null;
        }
    }

    // Function to sanitize data
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
        <title>Childcare Facilities</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .error {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:100px">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="Mountain.jpg" width="138px" height="138px" alt="logo" style="float:right" class="main-logo">
            <h1 style="color: white" style="float:clear">Smileside Childcare Facilities</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #9ad3de; text-align:center;">
                    <h3><strong>Login</strong></h3>
                    <span class="error"><strong><?php echo $loginErr ?></strong></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="loginName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="loginName" />
                                <span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameErr; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div><br /><br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="loginPass" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="loginPass" />
                                <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Log In" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="navbar-text pull-left">© 2016 - Built By Michal Patriak
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

My home page php (it's the only part causing this issue):

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['resultId'])) {      
        header("Location: index.php");  // Redirect to login page if not logged in 
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You left your password in plaintext, hope it is use no where else.

Comment: No, just an easy password for this project, but thank you for the heads up.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump($_SESSION); ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code
Instead of

```
$_SESSION['resultId'] = $result->fetch();
```

It should be

```
$_SESSION['resultId'] = $resultId['id'];
```

You have to check if session exist and then start the session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['resultId'])){
  header("Location: index.php");  // Redirect to login page
}
```

Comment: The code was originally set up that way, but when I realized the SESSION variable wasn't receiving a value I thought I would try to pull it directly from the fetch.

Comment: @MichalPatriak I have added some modification please check.

Comment: you can do this and check $resultId = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) 
    {
        session_start();
    }   


 if(!isset($_SESSION['resultId'])){
    header("Location: index.php");  // Redirect to login page
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to save SESSION in a Variable then apply it into your SQL query. it can reduce your single quote (') error.

```
 $uname=$_SESSION['loginName'];
  $pw=$_SESSION['loginPass'];

    $sql_login = "SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE `username` = '$uname' AND `password` = '$pw'";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql_login);
    $resultId = $result->fetch();
```

Try this :)